# How to parse an ISO formatted date in Flex (AS3)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datetime, parsing

How can I parse an ISO date string into a date object in Flex (AS3)?

e.g.
2009-12-08T04:23:23Z
2009-12-08T04:23:23.342-04:00
etc...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import com.adobe.utils.DateUtil;

var dateString:String = "2009-03-27T16:28:22.540-04:00";
var d:Date = DateUtil.parseW3CDTF(dateString);
trace(d);
var s:String = DateUtil.toW3CDTF(d);
trace(s);
```

```
[trace] Fri Mar 27 16:28:22 GMT-0400 2009
[trace] 2009-03-27T20:28:22-00:00
```

Turns out [DateUtil](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/as_libraries/docs/corelib/com/adobe/utils/DateUtil.html) handles everything in the [W3C Date and Time](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) spec. AS3 Dates do not maintain milliseconds, but they'll just be dropped if available.

Note that the W3C output is converted to UTC (aka GMT, or Zulu time).

Comment: It's a real shame that this solution only works with Flex because of the needed mx.formatters packages. So, if you're using Flash you're out of luck.

Comment: To use it without Flex, you can copy that one method out of DateUtil.as in as3corelib and paste it into your own class: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/utils/DateUtil.as

Answer (score 1):

Example function to convert ISO into Date format

```
    public function isoToDate(value:String):Date 
    {
        var dateStr:String = value;
        dateStr = dateStr.replace(/\-/g, "/");
        dateStr = dateStr.replace("T", " ");
        dateStr = dateStr.replace("Z", " GMT-0000");

        return new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/02/parsing-iso-dates-with-flex-and-actionscript/

(Sorry ff just isn't showing the linking button and I am too lazy to do it myself.)

Comment: Date.parse() does not work with ISO formats. It will return null.

Comment: The second link to the flexexamples blog is closer, though it doesn't handle anything but UTC (and only if specified with a trailing "Z" as opposed to a timezone offset. Thanks for helping look though!