# How do I pass object (ObjectProxy) from Flex back to .NET WebService?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, web-services, dataset

So, there are a wealth of Flex articles online about how to handle a .NET WebMethod that returns a `DataSet` or `DataTable`.  Here is an example:

[Handling web service results that contain .NET DataSets or DataTables](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_6.html#193946)

So, I know how to use `result.Tables.<tablename>.Rows` and the like. But what I cannot seem to figure out or find online is how to go the other direction - a method to pass objects or tables back to the .NET Webservice from Flex, **without stooping to passing XML as a string, or making huge web service methods that have one parameter for each property/column of the object being stored.**  Surely others, smarter than I, have tackled this issue.

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 Typed DataSets, and it would be really nice if I could just pass one object or array of objects from Flex to the web service, populate my Typed `DataTable`, and do an Update() through the corresponding typed TableAdapter.  My dream would be a `[WebMethod]` something like one of these:

```
public void SaveObject(TypedDataTable objToSave) { ... } 
public void SaveObject(TypedDataSet objToSave) { ... }
```

I've had the typed datatables saving to the database, I know how to do that part and even a few tricks, but we had [XML being passed back-and-forth as a string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpowell/archive/2004/05/12/130637.aspx) - eww.  I'm trying to get to a more object-based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best object based approach is [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format). I assume its probably a bit late in your your development cycle to change your integration layer, but otherwise I dont know of a way to get around marshalling your object(s) back into XML or separating them out into their primitive components.

For .NET implementations of AMF check out:

- [FlourineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/)(FOSS)
- [WebORB for .NET](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html)

Its amazing how easy things become once AMF is used, for example using the [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com) MVC framework and an AMF call passing a complex object to the server looks something like this:

```
<mate:RemoteObjectInvoker instance="yourWebservice"  method="saveComplexObject" showBusyCursor="true" >
    <mate:resultHandlers>
        <mate:CallBack method="saveComplexObjectSuccess" arguments="{[resultObject]}" />
    </mate:resultHandlers>
    <mate:faultHandlers>
        <mate:MethodInvoker generator="{DataManager}" method="presentFault" arguments="{fault}" />
    </mate:faultHandlers>
</mate:RemoteObjectInvoker>
```

With result and fault handlers being optional.

Comment: Hmm... interesting, though a cursory glance around the web (at FlourineFX) makes it look complicated to get setup compared to a webservice. But maybe the examples are just over-complicated setups.  Can it work with WebService methods? What about .NET typed datasets/datatables?

Comment: The setup is a tiny bit complicated (coming from a Java guy, so YMMV) but once set up, there is no additional config as you add services. As far as .Net typed objects, simply create the same Object in ActionScript, annotate it with the RemoteClass anotation: `[RemoteClass(alias="com.stackoverflow.somepackage.SomeObject")]`, and viola, you're done. The tech scales extremely well as you code grows, since that remote class registration is essentially the only config.

Comment: I was actually wondering how they specifically worked with Typed DataSets/Tables, but I suppose moving to LinqToSQL or EF would be wise if I was trying to go more purely object-based anyhow.

Comment: I did figure out another solution, a bit of a kluge, but I'll try to remember to post it on here sometime as it might help someone. Still, going to LinqToSQL/EF and/or using AMF sounds like a good idea.  I'm curious, which tool do you use - FlourineFX or WebORB?

Comment: Post it, it will help someone. I prefer SpringFlex (http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) above all others, but in the .NET world I'm currently using FluorineFX, mostly because its FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

The direction I ended up going was close to what I hoped was possible, but is "hack-ish" enough that I would consider SuperSaiyen's suggestion to use AMF/ORM a better solution for new/greenfield projects.

For sake of example/discussion, let's say I am working with a `Person` table in a database, and have a typed DataSet called `PeopleDataSet` that has `PersonTableAdapter` and `PersonDataTable` with it.

**READ** would look like this in .NET web service:

```
[WebMethod] 
public PeopleDataSet.PersonDataTable GetAllPeople() {
    var adapter = new PersonTableAdapter();
    return adapter.GetData();
}
```

... which in Flex would give you a `result` Object that you can use like this:

```
// FLEX (AS3)
something.dataProvider = result.Tables.Person.Rows;
```

Check out the link I put in the question for more details on how Flex handles that.

**CREATE/UPDATE** - This is the part I had to figure out, and why I asked this question. The Flex first this time:

```
// FLEX (AS3)
var person:Object = { 
    PersonID: -1,                // -1 for CREATE, actual ID for UPDATE
    FirstName: "John", 
    LastName: "Smith", 
    BirthDate: "07/19/1983",
    CreationDate: "1997-07-16T19:20+01:00" // need W3C DTF for Date WITH Time
};
_pplWebSvcInstance.SavePerson(person); // do the web method call
```

(For handling those W3C datetimes, see [How to parse an ISO formatted date in Flex (AS3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691342/how-to-parse-an-iso-formatted-date-in-flex-as3))

On the .NET web service side then, the trick was figuring out the correct Type on the web method's parameter. If you go with just `Object`, then step into a call with a debugger, you'll see .NET figures it is a `XmlNode[]`.  Here is what I figured out to do:

```
[WebMethod]
public int SavePerson(PeopleDataSet p) {
    // Now 'p' will be a PeopleDataSet with a Table called 'p' that has our data
    // row(s) (just row, in this case) as string columns in random order.
    // It WILL NOT WORK to use PeopleDataSet.PersonDataTable as the type for the
    // parameter, that will always result in an empty table. That is why the 
    // LoadFlexDataTable utility method below is necessary.

    var adapter = new PersonTableAdapter();
    var tbl = new PeopleDataSet.PersonDataTable();
    tbl.LoadFlexDataTable(p.Tables[0]); // see below

    // the rest of this might be familiar territory for working with DataSets
    PeopleDataSet.PersonRow row = tbl.FirstOrDefault();
    if (row != null) {
        if (row.PersonID > 0) {  // doing UPDATE
            row.AcceptChanges();
            row.SetModified();
        }
        else {  // doing CREATE
            row.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow; // set defaults here
            row.IsDeleted = false;
        }
        adapter.Update(row); // database call
        return row.PersonID;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now, the kluge utility method you saw called above. I did it as extension method, that is optional:

```
    // for getting the Un-Typed datatable Flex gives us into our Typed DataTable
    public static void LoadFlexDataTable(this DataTable tbl, DataTable flexDataTable)
    {            
        tbl.BeginLoadData();
        tbl.Load(flexDataTable.CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        tbl.EndLoadData();

        // Probably a bug, but all of the ampersand (&) in string columns will be
        // unecessarily escaped (&amp;) - kluge to fix it.
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            row.SetAdded(); // default to "Added" state for each row
            foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns) // fix &amp; to & on string columns
            {
                if (col.DataType == typeof(String) && !row.IsNull(col))
                    row[col] = (row[col] as string).Replace("&amp;", "&");
            }
        }
    }
```